# How to save an output file with Date and time stamp in robot framework?

Tags: excel, python-2.7, robotframework, selenium2library

I have an script that generates an .xls file at the end of execution. I would like to save this file with current system date and time. How can we achieve that in robot framework.

Output File path that I have given in my script looks like this.

Save Excel  E:\RobotFramework\Comparision\Resultfiles\Indice.xls

Answer (score 3):

Should be achievable easily using:

```
${timestamp} =    Get Current Date    result_format=%Y%m%d-%H%M
${filename} =    Set Variable    Put-whatever-you-want-here-eg-${timestamp}.xls
Save Excel    ${filename}
```

Just make sure you have DateTime library referenced in your script.

Comment: Hi, I have Implemented the steps you have mentioned and it gives me an error saying "invalid mode ('w+b') or filename:" u'E:\\RobotFramework\\Comparision\\Resultfiles\\2017-03-16 04:14:06.288.xls'

Comment: @Brother85 Yes indeed, with Get Current Date you still have to specify result format if you want to get characters compatible with filename. Try what's changed in the actual answer.